# How to open a file using the open with statement

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, file-io, io

I'm looking at how to do file input and output in Python. I've written the following code to read a list of names (one per line) from a file into another file while checking a name against the names in the file and appending text to the occurrences in the file. The code works. Could it be done better?

I'd wanted to use the `with open(...` statement for both input and output files but can't see how they could be in the same block meaning I'd need to store the names in a temporary location.

```
def filter(txt, oldfile, newfile):
    '''\
    Read a list of names from a file line by line into an output file.
    If a line begins with a particular name, insert a string of text
    after the name before appending the line to the output file.
    '''

    outfile = open(newfile, 'w')
    with open(oldfile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if line.startswith(txt):
                line = line[0:len(txt)] + ' - Truly a great person!\n'
            outfile.write(line)

    outfile.close()
    return # Do I gain anything by including this?

# input the name you want to check against
text = input('Please enter the name of a great person: ')    
letsgo = filter(text,'Spanish', 'Spanish2')
```

Comment: "meaning I'd need to store the names in a temporary location"?  Can you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: Note that `filter()` is [a built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)  and so you should probably choose a different name for your function.

Comment: @Tom does a function in the namespace override the built-in function?

Comment: @UpTide: Yes, Python operates in LEGB order -- Local, Enclosing, Global, Built-in (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules). So, if you make a global function (`filter()`), it will be found before the built-in `filter()`

Answer (score 391, accepted):

Python allows putting multiple `open()` statements in a single `with`.  You comma-separate them.   Your code would then be:

```
def filter(txt, oldfile, newfile):
    '''\
    Read a list of names from a file line by line into an output file.
    If a line begins with a particular name, insert a string of text
    after the name before appending the line to the output file.
    '''

    with open(newfile, 'w') as outfile, open(oldfile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if line.startswith(txt):
                line = line[0:len(txt)] + ' - Truly a great person!\n'
            outfile.write(line)

# input the name you want to check against
text = input('Please enter the name of a great person: ')    
letsgo = filter(text,'Spanish', 'Spanish2')
```

And no, you don't gain anything by putting an explicit `return` at the end of your function.  You can use `return` to exit early, but you had it at the end, and the function will exit without it.  (Of course with functions that return a value, you use the `return` to specify the value to return.)

Using multiple `open()` items with `with` was not supported in Python 2.5 when the `with` statement was introduced, or in Python 2.6, but it is supported in Python 2.7 and Python 3.1 or newer.

http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement
http://docs.python.org/release/3.1/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement

If you are writing code that must run in Python 2.5, 2.6 or 3.0, nest the `with` statements as the other answers suggested or use [`contextlib.nested`](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nested).

Answer (score 41):

Use nested blocks like this,

```
with open(newfile, 'w') as outfile:
    with open(oldfile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
        # your logic goes right here
```

Answer (score 14):

You can nest your with blocks. Like this:

```
with open(newfile, 'w') as outfile:
    with open(oldfile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if line.startswith(txt):
                line = line[0:len(txt)] + ' - Truly a great person!\n'
            outfile.write(line)
```

This is better than your version because you guarantee that `outfile` will be closed even if your code encounters exceptions. Obviously you could do that with try/finally, but `with` is the right way to do this.

Or, as I have just learnt, you can have multiple context managers in a with statement as [described by @steveha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282967/how-to-open-a-file-using-the-open-with-statement#answer-9283052). That seems to me to be a better option than nesting.

And for your final minor question, the return serves no real purpose. I would remove it.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes, you might want to open a variable amount of files and treat each one the same, you can do this with `contextlib`

```
from contextlib import ExitStack
filenames = [file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt]

with open('outfile.txt', 'a') as outfile:
    with ExitStack() as stack:
        file_pointers = [stack.enter_context(open(file, 'r')) for file in filenames]                
            for fp in file_pointers:
                outfile.write(fp.read())
```