# copy from one file to another - 'str' object has no attribute 'close'

Tags: python-2.7

i have this mini-script:

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    from sys import argv
    from os.path import exists

    p_script, p_from_file, p_to_file = argv

    print ('Copying from {first} to {second}'.format(first = p_from_file, 
                                                     second = p_to_file))

    v_in_file = (open(p_from_file, 'r')).read()
    print (v_in_file)

    print ('The input file is {size} bytes long'.format(size = len(v_in_file)))
    print ('Does the output file exists? {boolean}'.format(boolean = exists(p_to_file)))
    raw_input('Press return to continue...')

    v_out_file = open(p_to_file, 'w')
    v_out_file.write(v_in_file)

    print ('Alright, all done.')
    v_in_file.close()
    v_out_file.close()
```

Problem is..i can't close the file and i don't know why, what's the problem? "v_in_file.close()" doesn't executes properly.

Comment: `v_in_file` is **the data you `read` from the file**, not the file handle itself... Also, use the context manager `with`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `v_in_file` is a string evaluating to the contents of `p_from_file`. [(Python documentation)](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects). As such, it has no `close()` method.

You could instead write,

`v_in_file = open(p_from_file, 'r')
file_text = v_in_file.read()
v_in_file.close()`

or

`with open(p_from_file, 'r') as v_in_file:
    file_text = v_in_file.read()`

to automatically close the file [thanks for the reminder, jonrsharpe]

Comment: it was written like your first example, but i was asked to try to write it on a single line the whole thing..anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a file inside the ( ) and requesting the .read() method so resulting at a String value, after that you lose your file object

best way is to create the file to a variable and after you read from it, so you can close it properly after usage

Try this:

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

p_script, p_from_file, p_to_file = argv

print ('Copying from {first} to {second}'.format(first = p_from_file, 
                                                 second = p_to_file))

file_to_read = open(p_from_file, 'r')
v_in_file = file_to_read.read()
print (v_in_file)

print ('The input file is {size} bytes long'.format(size = len(v_in_file)))
print ('Does the output file exists? {boolean}'.format(boolean = exists(p_to_file)))
raw_input('Press return to continue...')

v_out_file = open(p_to_file, 'w')
v_out_file.write(v_in_file)

print ('Alright, all done.')
file_to_read.close()
v_out_file.close()
```

As per recommended by the buddie below you can check using with [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282967/how-to-open-a-file-using-the-open-with-statement)

Comment: You should use `with` for file handling, e.g. `with open(p_from_file) as file_to_read:`. Then you don't have to `close`.