# Function to open .txt file and print contents not working

Tags: python

This is my function:

```
def read_text():
    quotes = open("C:\blop\movie_quotes.txt")
    contents_of_file = quotes.read
    print(contents_of_file)
    quotes.close
read_text()
```

I am just trying to read a file and print the text within the file, but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:/Python27/detect_profanity.py", line 6, in <module>
read_text()File "C:/Python27/detect_profanity.py", line 2, in read_text
quotes = open("C:\blop\movie_quotes.txt")
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'C:\x08lop\\movie_quotes.txt'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Besides using `raw string` - `r"C:\blop\movie_quotes.txt"`, you should use [with open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282967/how-to-open-a-file-using-the-open-with-statement) instead of just `open`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the file `"C:\blop\movie_quotes.txt"` exists, Python is converting `\b` to `\x08` before passing it onto `open()` causing your issue. You should prepend your string with `r` so that it becomes a raw string, and `\b` does not get converted to anything (other than `\\b` , for escaping the `\`).

Another issue in your code is that you are doing - `contents_of_file = quotes.read`. This will just put the reference to the `read()` function in `contents_of_file` name. I think you want to read the contents of the file, so you should call the read function as - `contents_of_file = quotes.read()`.

Example:

```
def read_text():
    quotes = open(r"C:\blop\movie_quotes.txt")
    contents_of_file = quotes.read()
    print(contents_of_file)
    quotes.close()
read_text()
```

You can also, use the `with` statement here as:

```
def read_text():
    with open(r"C:\blop\movie_quotes.txt") as quotes:
        contents_of_file = quotes.read()
        print(contents_of_file)
read_text()
```

Comment: You forgot the reading mode, parentheses after `close()`, and the availability of `with open as`

Comment: You also forgot to indent the portion underneath `with`

Comment: Otherwise, great answer

Answer (score -1):

`'\b'` is a special character in Python. The same as `'\n'` is a special character meaning the newline character, and `'\t'` is the tab character, and `'\r'` is the carriage return character.

`'\\\\'` is a special character meaning the backslash character. So each time you  need a backslash, you need to escape it, and put two backslashes in order to print one.

`open("C:\blop\movie_quotes.txt")` should be `open("C:\\\\blop\\\\movie_quotes.txt")`

You have other errors in your code too. You are missing the parenthesis `()` after each function call, like `read()` or `close()`.

Comment: Build paths need one backslash and the OP does not have to escape the backslashes in a string. He can do something like `r"C:\blop\movie_quotes.txt"`. The `r` reads the backslashes as non-esscape characters. He only needs to escape the backslashes if he is doing something like `\n` in his string