# Writing to a file in python

Tags: python, flickr, writefile

In the following code I simply want to write the data I obtained from flickr in a neat way in a file for use later. However although the console throws no errors, nothing is being written to my file. Can anyone help me out with this, thank you in advance!

```
import flickrapi

api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
secret_api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, secret_api_key)

def obtainImages():

    photo_list = flickr.photos.search(api_key=api_key, has_geo=1, per_page = 500)
    file = open("obtainedImages.txt", "w")

    for photo in photo_list[0]:
        photo_location = flickr.photos_geo_getLocation(photo_id=photo.attrib['id'])

        id = str(photo[0].attrib['id'])
        lat = str(photo_location[0][0].attrib['latitude'])
        long = str(photo_location[0][0].attrib['longitude'])

        file.write("%s" %id)
        file.write(' ')
        file.write("%s" % lat)
        file.write(' ')
        file.write("%s" % long)
        file.write('\n')

obtainImages()
```

Here is updated code, that is again showing no errors but is not writing anything to the file. Lat and lon are printing ok

```
import flickrapi

api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
secret_api_key = "xxxxxxxxx"
flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, secret_api_key)

def obtainImages():

    photo_list = flickr.photos.search(api_key=api_key, has_geo=1, per_page = 500)
    file = open("obtainedImages.txt", "w")

    for photo in photo_list[0]:

        photo_location = flickr.photos_geo_getLocation(photo_id=photo.attrib['id'])
        lat = str(photo_location[0][0].attrib['latitude'])
        long = str(photo_location[0][0].attrib['longitude'])

        file.write("%s" % lat)
        file.write(' ')
        file.write("%s" % long)
        file.write('\n')

    file.close()
obtainImages()
```

Comment: Did you `print photo_list[0]`?

Comment: technically, you should call `file.close()` when you are done writing, though some implementations take care of this for you.

Comment: I've tried that and I have tried printing lat and long etc out before I attempted to write to the file and it worked fine, it just so happens when I try to write to the file there are no errors but nothing is written into my file

Comment: maybe you should use exceptions such as IOError to see if w=everything is fine

Comment: I have added in file.close(), and have check the printing again. Lat and long are printing fine however id is not. I removed id and it ran ok again but with no writing, but now  having put in file.close(), my error says "line 20, in obtainImages
    file.write("%s" % lat)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file"

Comment: I have applied all of your suggestions(see updated code above) and am still getting the same problem of no errors but nothing is written to the file, I am stumped!

Comment: Which txt file are you checking if it's written or not? The one that is in the same directory with your `.py` file, right?

Comment: I mean, where are your `.txt` and `.py` files located?

Comment: please give a minimal example - is this about writing to a file or about flickr? Often when reducing the code to something simple you will find the problem yourself.

Comment: I tested the file-writing part with hard-coded values for id, lat and long, and it worked fine.  I would try to print the values you're  getting to the console and see if there is a problem with what flickrapi is giving you.

Comment: One more comment: `id()` and `long()` are built-in functions in python 2.7, and `id()` is a built-in function in python 3.x, so while python will let you name variables `id` and `long`, it's a very risky practice - so just never do it.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `file.close()` at the end of your `obtainImages()` method.

```
def obtainImages():

    photo_list = flickr.photos.search(api_key=api_key, has_geo=1, per_page = 500)
    file = open("obtainedImages.txt", "w")

    for photo in photo_list[0]:
        photo_location = flickr.photos_geo_getLocation(photo_id=photo.attrib['id'])

        id = str(photo[0].attrib['id'])
        lat = str(photo_location[0][0].attrib['latitude'])
        long = str(photo_location[0][0].attrib['longitude'])

        file.write("%s" %id)
        file.write(' ')
        file.write("%s" % lat)
        file.write(' ')
        file.write("%s" % long)
        file.write('\n')
    file.close()  ## add here
```

Comment: Alternatively, [use `with`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282967/how-to-open-a-file-using-the-open-with-statement) so you won't forget to close it.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following

1. The file `obtainedImages.txt` is in the same directory as the python
   file.
2. When you run the python file, you are closing & re-opening the `.txt` file to check for changes
3. Move your cursor around the file and check if the spaces and newline are getting written, if yes that means there is something
       wrong with the values

If you still do not get output, try the following debugging steps:

1. Replace `lat` & `long` with static values and see if they are written to file.
2. Comment out the `for` loop and check if the values are written to file (Re-indent the `for` block when you comment the `for` loop)
3. It is possible that the file you are writing to is not the one you are reading from. So you could open the file in *read mode* and try to print its contents using a python script.