# Opening Files in python an integer is required error

Tags: python-3.x, text-files

I am trying to open a file in python but I keep getting the error "an integer is required"

My code:

```
    print("This is console module")

    import random

    def randomNumber(myFile):


    times=0

    print("Generating numbers...")

       while times != 10:
           random=random.randint(1, 100)
           print("\nNumber generated: "+str(random))
           myFile.write(random)
           times+1

       myFile.close()
       print("Done")




   myFile = open("NUMBERS.TXT", "a", "wt", "rt")

   randomNumber(myFile)

   myFile.close()
```

I want it to print random numbers to a file

Comment: can you indent your code?

Comment: ...and start using the ["with" statement to open your files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9282967/2615940)

Comment: I was taught to open files like that.

Comment: @ThePlumBOB179 Well... languages change over time, and the way you do things needs to change accordingly. Using `with` has been the preferred way to open files for years now. The person that taught you to open files without it was probably not keeping up with Python developments.

Comment: No, I was taught, like, a week ago. Not to be rude.