# How to convert a list of strings into a list of integers - many things dont seem to work

Tags: python, list

I have a problem. I would like to convert a list of strings with 594 elements, among them many empty, to a list of integers. I already looked up many answers here, but neither list comprehensions, neither map function seems to work. My command prompt simply says int argument must be a string or a number, not a list.

Here is my code:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) < 1 : fname = "regex_sum_317625.txt"
fh = open(fname)

import re
numlist = list()

for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    numbers = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
    numlist.append(numbers)

print numlist
listlength = len(numlist)
print listlength

intlist = [int(nums) for nums in numlist]
print intlist
```

I tried many ways, but the problem always is that I try to do an operation on a list which is not allowed. Could you please help me, what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approaches you mentioned should work, but you're not building your data correctly; you don't have a list of strings but a list of lists - `re.findall` *returns* a list:

```
numbers = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
numlist.append(numbers) # appending a list to numlist
```

You should instead *extend* `numlist` with the results of `re.findall` using the `extend` method of the list:

```
numlist.extend(numbers)
```

The `list.extend` method will

> *extend* the list by appending all the items in the given list.

---

Since you're already familiar with comprehensions, you might as well use a comprehension in place of the `for` loop:

```
with open(fname) as fh:
    int_list = [int(item) for line in fh for item in re.findall('[0-9]+', line)]
```

I noticed, you did not call the `close` method of your file object `fh`. You can let Python do the cleanup for you by opening the file *with* a context manager, using the `with` statement.

See [How to open a file using the open with statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282967/how-to-open-a-file-using-the-open-with-statement) to learn more about this.