# Why does my program skip the last element (tesla) when writing to Stocks.txt?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

i was just wondering why my program, even though it finds the data, cannot write tesla's data even though it writes the data of every other stock. Here is my code:

```
import requests, bs4, logging

stocks = {"google":"694653","amazon":"660463","apple":"22144","hack":"898127760101820","facebook":"296878244325128",
          "biotech":"700203","construction":"705971","nvidia":"662925","netflix":"672501","tesla":"12607212","":""}

new = open("Stocks.txt","w")

for stock in stocks:

    website = requests.get("https://www.google.ca/finance?cid=" + stocks[stock])
    website.raise_for_status()

    html = bs4.BeautifulSoup(website.text,"html.parser")

    price = (html.select(("#ref_%s_l") % stocks[stock])[0]).getText()
    change = (html.select(("#ref_%s_cp") % stocks[stock])[0]).getText()

    today = open("Stocks.txt","a")
    today.write(stock + ": " + price + "  " + change + 2*"\n")
```

Comment: Did you try erese the last key value? "":"" I mean, why is that there?

Comment: Don't forget to close your files: `today.close()`

Comment: Hi Damian, I just put it there to test things out. I deleted it but its still not working

Comment: patrick!!!!!!!! It worked!!! Thanks so much. I owe you one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way of avoiding these kind of file closing issues is to use the `with` construction:

Replace for instance

```
new = open("Stocks.txt","w")
```

with

```
with open("Stocks.txt","w") as new:
    new.write ("XXX")
    #you can do all kinds of stuff here
```

This will automatically close the file after you are done with the indented part. You can read up on this [here](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) and in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282967/how-to-open-a-file-using-the-open-with-statement).