# Python error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I am trying to open the file from folder and read it but it's not locating it. I am using Python3

Here is my code:

```
import os
import glob

prefix_path = "C:/Users/mpotd/Documents/GitHub/Python-Sample-                
codes/Mayur_Python_code/Question/wx_data/"
target_path = open('MissingPrcpData.txt', 'w')
file_array = [os.path.abspath(f) for f in os.listdir(prefix_path) if 
f.endswith('.txt')]
file_array.sort() # file is sorted list

for f_obj in range(len(file_array)):
     file = os.path.abspath(file_array[f_obj])
     join_file = os.path.join(prefix_path, file) #whole file path

for filename in file_array:
     log = open(filename, 'r')#<---- Error is here
```

`Error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'USC00110072.txt'`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not giving the full path to a file to the `open()`, just its name - a relative path.

Non-absolute paths specify locations in relation to current [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) (CWD, see [`os.getcwd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd)).

You would have to either `os.path.join()` correct directory path to it, or `os.chdir()` to the directory that the files reside in.

**Also, remember that [`os.path.abspath()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) can't deduce the full path to a file just by it's name.** It will only prefix its input with the path of the current working directory, if the given path is relative.

Looks like you are forgetting to modify the the `file_array` list. To fix this, change the first loop to this:

```
file_array = [os.path.join(prefix_path, name) for name in file_array]
```

---

Let me reiterate.

This line in your code:

```
file_array = [os.path.abspath(f) for f in os.listdir(prefix_path) if f.endswith('.txt')]
```

is wrong. It will not give you a list with correct absolute paths. What you should've done is:

```
import os
import glob

prefix_path = ("C:/Users/mpotd/Documents/GitHub/Python-Sample-"    
               "codes/Mayur_Python_code/Question/wx_data/")
target_path = open('MissingPrcpData.txt', 'w')
file_array = [f for f in os.listdir(prefix_path) if f.endswith('.txt')]
file_array.sort() # file is sorted list

file_array = [os.path.join(prefix_path, name) for name in file_array]

for filename in file_array:
     log = open(filename, 'r')
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using relative path where you should be using an absolute one. It's a good idea to use `os.path` to work with file paths. Easy fix for your code is:

```
prefix = os.path.abspath(prefix_path) 
file_list = [os.path.join(prefix, f) for f in os.listdir(prefix) if f.endswith('.txt')]
```

Note that there are some other issues with your code:

1. In python you can do `for thing in things`. You did `for thing in range(len(things))` it's much less readable and unnecessary.
2. You should use context managers when you open a file. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9283052/4190925).

Comment: 1. for your first note: it's helping me to get the location of each file in the folder.                                                                                                       2. I have used your suggestion and still, it's showing me an error.

Comment: I have the same issues.  I am using ciscoconfparse module in Python to read and parse several cisco config files.  It worked for the first 10 config files in a folder okay.  When I added additional configs into the same folder, it gave me the [FATAL] ciscoconfparse could not open error for the new configs I added.