# Extract lines from a txt file in python

Tags: python, text-extraction

Imagine I have this text in a txt file:

> bla bla bla 
> bla bla bla
> Title Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
> elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore 
> magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
> condition
> bla bla bla
> bla bla bla
> Title Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem 
> accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam,
> eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis 
> condition
> bla bla bla

From the text with the structure above (hundred of lines), I want to extract the lines that start with 'title' until I find the line that starts with the word 'condition'. So the result would be something like this:

**Title Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,**

**Title Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis**

I get to select the first like with this code, but I don't know how to add the next lines until I find the word 'condition'. Could you help me, please?

````
outF = open("myOutFile.txt", "w")
hand = open('doubt.txt', encoding="utf8")
for line in hand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.search('^Title',line) :       
       outF.write(line); outF.write("\n")
       outF.write("\n")
outF.close()```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want all titles until the first condition line appears, you need to [`break`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue) the loop:

```
for line in hand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith("Title"):       
       outF.writelines([line])
    if line.startswith("condition"):
         break

outF.close()
```

In case you want to write all lines after a title till the next condition appears:

```
write = False
writelines = []

for line in hand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    
    if line.startswith("condition"):
       write = False
       writelines.append("\n")
       
    if line.startswith("Title"):       
       write = True
    
    if write:
         writelines.append(line + " ")

outF.writelines(writelines)  
outF.close()
```

Comment: This would only ever give you the first title/condition

Comment: @Sayse It was my understanding that Title-lines should be added until the first condition line appears. The question's formatting is a bit misleading, but "Title Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing" is only one line in the example.

Comment: The result output the op has included in their question would suggest they expect to find two matches

Comment: @Sayse OK. I might have misinterpreted the question. Added solutions for both cases.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach I added a minor change, as its concatenates all lines in a single line. As I want separated lines each time I find 'Title' I put:

    if line.startswith("condition"):
       write = False
       writelines.append("\n")

I guess you might have a better solution.

I still have the problem that when it appends two lines, the program doesn't put a space, for instance:

Title Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit, sed do

Title Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do

Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @nekovolta OK, thanks for the edit. Regarding the extra space: That's easy, we just add a space when we add the line to the list of `writelines`. I've just updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Thank you again. I manage to find a similar solution that is the next one:

    if write:
         writelines.append(line)
         writelines.append(space)

But yours is much more elegant. I know my questions are very basic, but I really appreciate your support as I am a total beginner with python. I guess that I will have more questions because this was just the first step :)

Comment: @nekovolta It's fine. We all have been beginners in the beginning. Happy I could be of help :) It is not part of the question, but you might also be interested in the open-context. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282967/how-to-open-a-file-using-the-open-with-statement