# Reading a file in python and sending contents to two different variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I am trying to read the file and put the two sequences (ie Spar and Sbay) into two variables seq1 and seq2. So far I only know how to pass everything to one sequence by using this code.

```
filename = 'AQY2.fasta'
readfile = open(filename, 'r')
seq1 = ''
seq2 = ''
for line in readfile.readlines():
     if ( line[0] == '>' ):
         header = line[1:]
     else:
         seq1 = seq1 + line

readfile.close() 
print(seq1)
```

Can anyone help me to read the two sequences into seq1 and seq2?

[The image contains two sequences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZMfG.png)

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you mean, but you can add `seq2 = seq2 + line` just below `seq1 = seq1 + line` (with the same indentation, that's important!). You might also want to print `seq2` as well, to check it's ok, so add `print(seq2)` below `print(seq1)`. Finally, you should probably handle the file with `with`, but that's maybe for another time.

Comment: Please paste text not images of text or links to images of text

Comment: FYI, there are libraries for parsing FASTA files in Python, you don't have to code it yourself.

Comment: To follow up on what Barmar said, check out Biopython or [pyfaidx](https://github.com/mdshw5/pyfaidx). There's a lot of examples with Biopython in their documentation and at Biostars.org. Both of those separate each sequence record/entry without you needing to code it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using two vaiable `matchSpar` and `matchSbay` to read the file and seq a dictionary to store the corresponding result.

if `matchSpar` is set to `True` then lines added append to `'>Spar'` key in `seq` dictionary if `matchSbay` is set to `True` then lines added append to `'>Sbay'` key in `seq` dictionary.

```
filename = 'AQY2.fasta'
readfile = open(filename, 'r')
seq= {
        '>Spar' : "",
        '>Sbay' : ""
        }
matchSpar = False
matchSbay = False
lines = []
for line in readfile.readlines():
    line = line.replace('\n', '')
    if line == '>Spar':
        matchSpar = True
        matchSbay = False

    if line == '>Sbay':
        matchSpar = False
        matchSbay = True

    if matchSpar :
        seq[">Spar"] += line+"\n"
    if matchSbay :
        seq[">Sbay"] += line+"\n"

readfile.close() 

print(seq['>Spar'])
print(seq['>Sbay'])
```

Its recommended to use [with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282967/how-to-open-a-file-using-the-open-with-statement) `keyword` to file handling in python :

```
filename = 'AQY2.fasta'
seq= {
        '>Spar' : "",
        '>Sbay' : ""
        }
matchSpar = False
matchSbay = False

with open(filename, 'r') as readfile:
 for line in readfile.readlines():
    if line == '>Spar\n':
        matchSpar = True
        matchSbay = False

    if line == '>Sbay\n':
        matchSpar = False
        matchSbay = True

    if matchSpar :
        seq[">Spar"] += line
    if matchSbay :
        seq[">Sbay"] += line

print(seq['>Spar'])
print(seq['>Sbay'])
```